# How to publish Web Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

hay for the last week im having real trouble with my site.

i hed a simple site that when i wanted to check it online ive just upload all the files to a online server http://www.aspspider.com/ and every thing work BUT i didnt hed any server side code(all the CodeBhind files were just empty).

then i start adding some server side code and check it localy and it work fine.

Now im having trouble uploading the site to the server im getting all sort of error when im trying to access it.

i ask some questions about my problem but nothing work so im thinking mybee i just dont know how to upload the file correctly.

so my questions are:
 1.why i just upload all the files ( the CodeBhind's and designer.cs's) to the server?

2.what its the best way to publish/deploy the site befor uploading it to a host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20yh9f1b(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: my project is Web-Appliction and the guide say "This topic applies only to Web site projects".

Comment: this is how i publish my site every time,only i dont have this -Allow this precompiled site to be updateable or -Enable strong naming on precompiled assemblies options when i publish it like the guide say.

Answer (score 1):

How are you uploading the site, through FTP?
Then if i were you i would publish it to local file system and then upload it through FTP.

Comment: i publish the site with file system but im uploading it manuly i dont know how to use ftp to upload it can you give me a link to a guide?

Comment: If you can reach the server through file system publish then you shouldn't have any problems. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: parser error i asked a question yesterday on that, but im starting to think is not the problem.

Comment: Have you created the virtual directory on IIS and marked the "Set Application Root" setting?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have admin rights or is it hosted? Did you upload the bin directory and its contents?
If you have FTP access you should be able to publish directly from your solution in VS.

Comment: im pretty new at all this so im not sure about the admin rights im using www.aspspider.com for hosting my site. i did upload the bin. im publishing my site zip all the file/folders and upload to the server and then extract it there.